# Error while building an android app or web using flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlPFn.png)I encounter this error when I build an application or web and right now idk how i can fix this

name: beshiefy_source_code
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
uses-material-design: true

Expected to find fonts for (MaterialIcons,
packages/cupertino_icons/CupertinoIcons), but found (MaterialIcons). This usually
means you are referring to font families in an IconData class but not including
them in the assets section of your pubspec.yaml, are missing the package that
would include them, or are missing "uses-material-design: true".
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184
to 7548 bytes (99.5% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the
--no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             42.0s

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you fail to create project or build release file?